# Delphi: how to do digital signature with timestamp of files?

Tags: delphi, digital-signature

Many customers of mine use a software for doing digital signatures. This software is called Dike and it is provided from the italian chamber of commerce and it interfaces to **smart card** hardware like [this](http://ebusiness.infocert.it/nemo/home.do?category=CFD).

Now I would like from my application to do the digital signatures, bypassing the software that does it.

Is it possible to do this in Delphi, did anyone already did it? I would like to add timestamp too.

NOTE FOR BOUNTY:
I don't know how this is important outside of Italy, anyway in Italy there is a law that requires that certain documents are stored with particular rules. TO implmemetn this it is mandatory to digital sign and put a time stamp on the file (pfd files).
Basically I ask "is it there anyonw that already imlpemented this in Delphi and found a succesful way. Can you share your results?".
Basically there is a million of USB smartcard readers, I don't want to start supporting million of drivers in my application (I write an app that is in part a document management system), if there were seomthing like TWAIN is there for image scanner it would be great.

I could also accept the limitation to link to a specific hardware, so I can say if you want this feature you must buy this hardware, I don't want to support all the existing hardware or timestamp/digital signatures web services.
So what I am looking for is Time Stamp and Digital Signature for pdf files for Delphi 1-0-1. I hope I expressed my self if not please ask.

Comment: To find out if you can do the same thing in all software, You'll need to get the technical specifications of the digitial signature algorithms and protocols.

Comment: Some documentation about **DiKe** (Digital Key) seems to be here: https://www.firma.infocert.it/installazione/installazione_DiKe.php

Answer (score 6):

Our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/delphi-pki.php) product provides full scope of PKI functionality including signing and timestamping data using CMS and CAdES formats and certificates can be located on PKCS#11-compatible smartcards. If you are looking for [PDF signing](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/delphi-pdf.php) and timestamping, then SecureBlackbox supports them as well (via PAdES standard).

SecureBlackbox is available for Delphi 4 to XE2 and supports 64-bit Windows.

We have clients form Italy who do exactly what you need.

Comment: I accept this since in principle it solves my problem, I had no time to evaluate the product but it seems it can solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You mays also look at [Gnostice PDFToolkit VCL](http://www.gnostice.com/PDFtoolkit_VCL.asp) wich allow you to "edit, secure, merge, split, view, digitally sign PDF documents".

Comment: Are you sure they work with certificates on hardware devices?

Comment: No it does'nt, but the question is not clear (for me) about the mandatory of a hardware solution.

Comment: This is written in bold on the second line.

Comment: @relativ, You can do the same :) And furthermore, you don't have any info at your profile, so it will look independent for the others ;)

Answer (score 0):

with signtool:

```
  c:\BinPath\signtool.exe sign /f c:\BinPath\Mypfxfile.pfx /p MyPassword 
  /t http:// timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll c:\BinPath\Project1.exe
```